# I need help (write and read function) c++

Tags: c++, function, class

The program is working in this way. But I need to change the price system. I need to use priceRead and priceWrite.

```
priceRead (): double 
priceWrite (in _price: double): void
```

priceRead: price is a function to read the property. 
priceWrite (double): price property is a function of writing.

Sorry for bad english. :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class shoes{
    protected:  
              int size;
              string colour;
              char sex;
              string brand; 
    public: shoes(int _size, string _colour, char _sex, string _brand)
                    :size(_size),colour(_colour), sex(_sex), brand(_brand)
                    {cout << "shoe configurator" << endl;} 
            ~shoes(){ }
            void shoesInf();

};

class storage{
    protected:
              int number;
              int maxsize;
              int minsize;
    public: storage(int _number, int _maxsize, int _minsize)
                    :number(_number),maxsize(_maxsize),minsize(_minsize)
                    {cout << "store configurator" << endl;} 
            ~storage(){ } 
            void storageInf();

};

void shoes::shoesInf()
{

    cout << "Size :" << size << endl;
    cout << "Colour :" << colour << endl;
    cout << "Sex :" << ((sex=='M')?"Man":"Woman") << endl;
    cout << "Brand:" << brand << endl;
}

void storage::storageInf()
{
    cout << "Number :" << number << endl;
    cout << "Max size :" << maxsize << endl;
    cout << "Min size :" << minsize << endl;
}   

class Store: public storage{
    private:  int number;
              int maxsize;
              int minsize;
    public: Store(int _number, int _maxsize, int _minsize)
                  :storage(_number,_maxsize,_minsize)
                {cout << "storage INF" << endl;}    


};

class Nike: public shoes{
    private:  double price;
    public: Nike(int _size, string _colour, char _sex, string _brand,
                 double _price):shoes(_size,_colour,_sex,_brand),price(_price)
                {cout << "Shoes INF" << endl;}  

            void shoesInf()
            {
                ((shoes*)this)->shoesInf();
                cout << "Price :" << price << endl;
            }


};

class Lacoste: public shoes{
    private:  double price;
    public: Lacoste(int _size, string _colour, char _sex, string _brand,
                 double _price):shoes(_size,_colour,_sex,_brand),price(_price)
                {cout << "Shoes INF" << endl;}  



            void shoesInf()
            {
                ((shoes*)this)->shoesInf();
                cout << "Price:" << price<< endl;
            }


};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Store*sh=new Store(1,50,15);
    sh->storageInf();
    Nike *sh2=new Nike(38,"Blue",'F',"Nike",100);
    sh2->shoesInf();
    Lacoste *sh3=new Lacoste(40,"Yellow",'M',"Lacoste",350);
    sh3->shoesInf();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. All you state is "I need to use priceRead and priceWrite". Well, then just use them. The best chance for getting someone to help you with a good answer is to ask a good question.

Comment: I don't know how to use it. That's the problem.

Comment: Could you give us more information about this: `But I need to change the price system`. What do you need to change, what exactly do you need to do?

Comment: It's very hard to understand your question. What don't you know how to use? The `priceRead` and `priceWrite` functions don't exist yet, as far as I can tell, so you *can't* use them. You need to create them. And to do that, you need to know what they're supposed to do. If you don't know what they're supposed to do, how do you know you need to create them?!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Shoes
{
private:
    int size;
    string colour;
    char sex;
    string brand;
    double price;
public:
    Shoes(int _size, string _colour, char _sex, string _brand, double _price) : 
    size(_size), colour(_colour), sex(_sex), brand(_brand), price(_price)
    {}

    void writePrice(double newPrice)
    {
        price = newPrice;
    }

    void readPrice()
    {
        cout << price << endl;
    }
};
```

Notes:

- All shoes have a price, so why not just put it in the base class?
- Brand is defined by the brand string, all shoes are the same, so no need to derive a new class for each brand.
- No need to have an empty destructor.
- Also, without this redefinition of `price` when deriving, you don't have to redefine `shoeInf` everytime you want to derive from `Shoe`.
- One more thing: Start class names with `CapitalLetters` (in that style!).